# Validation methods beside POW etc

Tags: blockchain, proof-of-work, proof-of-stake, validation

Are there other concepts for the validation of the next added block to the blockchain beside POW, POS etc.?

Of cource there are, but is there a methode that is shining out of the mass?
A methode that can be a future mechanismen better than the current ones? That needs alot less electricity etc. to validate blocks?

Answer (score -1):

None that is secure in a decentralized environment. Only PoW is secure.